# Angular 2 @types/jquery through error while compiling

Tags: angular, typescript-typings

I am installing jquery typings in Angular 2 by using

```
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

after that when I compile my code using **npm start** It through me error

```
[default] /home/rahul/Documents/codebase/dcn_web/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:3789:13 
    Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'jQuery' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'JQueryStatic'.
[default] Checking finished with 1 errors
```

How I resolve It.